# Google App Engine for java: my peoject structure is diffrent

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build my first google app engine application "**hello world**" , I am:

1. using eclipse (**mars 1**)
2. I installed : Google plugin for Eclipse / SDKs ( GAE java sdk (1.9.34) + Google      Web Toolkit SDK 2.7.0 )
3. using **JDK 7** (instead of 8) and my path variable is well set, as well as preferences in eclipse ( the compiler 1.7)

   And when i want to create a new web application ( the zone of **sample code**   -*generate project sample code*-  doesn't appear at all) and the structure of the project is totally different from what it should look like. When run ( as web app) the browser keeps throwing **HTTP 404** error ( localhost:8888 as well )

Answer (score 0):

I FIND OUT WHAT WAS THE PROBLEME :

I have downloaded the wrong plugin for my eclipse mars.here is the right link https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.5 to add in eclipse( help ->install new software .

Note: one more thing, make sure while creating a new google app engine project, to uncheck the : use GTW [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZa2j.png)